# android gradle, use different dependency version in android testing environment

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing

I have a project that depends on a dependency, say 'mygroup:myartifect:myversion', normally I would add this to my build.gradle

```
compile 'mygroup:myartifect:myversion'
```

but during android test, I would like to use a different version of the same dependency, say myversion2. If I add

```
androidTestCompile 'mygroup:myartifect:myversion2'
```

I would run into an error said:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
> Error: more than one library with package name 'mygroup.myartifect'
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could have two different dependencies files.

`dependencies {
   if(test)
    apply from:'testdependencies.gradle'
   else
    apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'
}`

When you run task, set 'test' variable to true.

OR

you could have

`compile 'my group:myartifect:myversion'
testCompile 'my group:myartifect:myversion2'`

Comment: Using your first method, I run into an issue said that `ould not find property 'test' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@b7f5fab`. and the second method would cause another error: `Error: more than one library with package name 'mygroup.myartifect'`

Comment: You need to define a property 'def test'. set it to true when you have to run tests. By default set it to false. The second method should work as well. Could you please paste the package name and version details.

Comment: Hi  prijupaul, the dependency is from my own company, I'm not sure if its confidential. But when I first add `compile ...` and then `androidTestCompile ...` with a different version. The error did occur. I'm using the `@aar` format though, I'm not sure if it's related. As for the first method, may I ask how can I do that? I tried myself, but didn't come out with a working solution.